# how to save last selected Option in a file JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, save, drop-down-menu, hta

i have here an HTA and theres is a selectbox named like this: object.select1.options
I want to save the selected value from this box in a file located on C-Partition. When the user restart the programm the default selection in this checkbox should be the last selection. So my programm already creates the text file and write in it. Hope you can help me. Its JavaScript.

Edit:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
object.select1.options = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt", 1, false);
```

when i use this i get an error which says file not found what did i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Runtime scripting uses URLs as well. You write your code:

```
object.select1.options = fso.OpenTextFile("c:/Temp/CAD_Kunde.txt", 1, false);
```

or

```
object.select1.options = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\Temp\\CAD_Kunde.txt", 1, false);
```

Single backslash represents an escape character.